# Application alias rewrite using apache

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am new to apache and i am trying to rewrite an application default alias to a more elegant one using apache but unfortunately i struggle and i can't find a way to do it

Can you help me please ?

What i want :

- Server name is (for example) server0123456.com
- my app is located at server0123456.com:8080/myapp_backend
- A dns alias ( cname?) was created for the server : mycompany.com
- mycompany.com/myapp_backend is working well (with RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp_backend/ [R=302,L,NE]
- But i want the url to be mycompany.com/myapp which is more elegant
- If mycompany.com is pinged it must redirect to mycompany.com/myapp

Here is what i tried

My vh file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName mycompany.com
 DocumentRoot "/hawai/composants/apache/htdocs"

  <Directory />
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  EnableMCPMReceive
  RewriteEngine On
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^STATUS.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^INFO.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^CONFIG.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^ENABLE-APP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^DISABLE-APP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^STOP-APP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^STOP-APP-RSP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^REMOVE-APP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^STATUS-RSP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^INFO-RSP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^DUMP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^DUMP-RSP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^PING$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^PING-RSP$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test.html.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mod_cluster_manager/.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status/.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance.html$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static_myapp/.*$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myapp_backend/.*$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp/ [R=302,L,NE]

</VirtualHost>
```

My location file :

```
<Location "/myapp_backend/">
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
    
  # mod_deflate
  #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml 
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
    # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
    # workaround to get the desired effect:
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary 
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</Location>

DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio
DeflateCompressionLevel 7
```

Do i need to add proxypass ?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: How do `server0123456.com` and `mycompany.com` relate to each other?

Comment: @MrWhite thank you for your reply , i added some extra informations. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Comment: Directory / points to / in your operative system, you should define your documentroot. Also, assuming you are using 2.4, stop using directives Order/Allow. About your issue it is not clear where you are app is, if it is a real directory perhaps a typical alias would do 'Alias /myapp/ /myapp_backend/'. The real config depends largely on whatś going on, so I suggest you document the question much better.